# Dynamic input to Fusion charts

Tags: fusioncharts

I am trying to pass a dynamic input to the fusion chart on a JSP page. I am actually trying to render a bar chart for which I am not sure about the number of columns. In the below snippet, in the data part, I need to pass the number of variables dynamically. Is it possible? Can someone help

```
                data: [
                    {

                        "label": "Inprogress",
                        "value": "<%=cummulativeInprogress%>"

                    }, 
                    {
                        "label": "Completed",
                        "value": "<%=cummulativeCompleted%>"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "label": "Aborted",
                        "value": "<%=cummulativeAborted%>"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "label": "Failed",
                        "value": "<%=cummulativeFailed%>"
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "Cancelled",
                        "value": "<%=cummulativeCancelled%>"
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "Amending",
                        "value": "<%=cummulativeAmending%>"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }).render();
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a json object to the fusioncharts engine to render the chart. Then in case you need to change the data plot, you can make another ajax call to get a new json object and refresh the chart display.

Answer (score 0):

You can try by implementing below section of code -

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@page import="java.util.*" %>
<%@page import="fusioncharts.FusionCharts" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<title>FusionCharts | Simple Chart Using Array</title>
<link href="../Styles/ChartSampleStyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.fusioncharts.com/fusioncharts/latest/fusioncharts.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.fusioncharts.com/fusioncharts/latest/themes/fusioncharts.theme.fusion.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<h3>Simple Chart Using Array</h3>  
 <div id="chart"></div>
 <div><span><a href="../Index.jsp">Go Back</a></span></div>
 <%
 // store chart config name-config value pair
 Map<String, String> chartConfig = new HashMap<String, String>();
 chartConfig.put("caption", "Countries With Most Oil Reserves [2017-18]");
 chartConfig.put("subCaption", "In MMbbl = One Million barrels");
 chartConfig.put("xAxisName", "Country");
 chartConfig.put("yAxisName", "Reserves (MMbbl)");
 chartConfig.put("numberSuffix", "k");
 chartConfig.put("theme", "fusion");
 
 //store label-value pair
 Map<String, Integer> dataValuePair = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
 dataValuePair.put("Venezuela", 290);
 dataValuePair.put("Saudi", 260);
 dataValuePair.put("Canada", 180);
 dataValuePair.put("Iran", 140);
 dataValuePair.put("Russia", 115);
 dataValuePair.put("UAE", 100);
 dataValuePair.put("US", 30);
 dataValuePair.put("China", 30);
 
  StringBuilder jsonData = new StringBuilder();
  StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();
  // json data to use as chart data source
  jsonData.append("{'chart':{");
  for(Map.Entry conf:chartConfig.entrySet())
  {
      jsonData.append("'" + conf.getKey()+"':'"+conf.getValue() + "',");
  }
 
  jsonData.replace(jsonData.length() - 1, jsonData.length() ,"},");

  // build  data object from label-value pair
  data.append("'data':[");

  for(Map.Entry pair:dataValuePair.entrySet())
  {
      data.append("{'label':'" + pair.getKey() + "','value':'" + pair.getValue() +"'},");
  }
  data.replace(data.length() - 1, data.length(),"]");

  jsonData.append(data.toString());
  jsonData.append("}");
  
  
//Create chart instance
  // charttype, chartID, width, height,containerid, data format, data
  FusionCharts firstChart = new FusionCharts(
          "column2d", 
          "first_chart", 
          "800",
          "550", 
          "chart",
          "json", 
          jsonData.toString()
 );
 %>
 <%= firstChart.render() %>
</body>
</html>
```

Refer the doc - https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/getting-started/java/configure-your-chart-using-java